# What is the difference between using width/height vs. position to make an element entirely fill its parent?

Tags: css

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

vs.

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Are there any advantages to either technique?

Comment: the latter one is to ignore border, padding, margin I suppose..

Comment: Good point, I'm using border-box and have no margin so I didn't think of that.

Comment: Setting the latter causes 100% height and width, whereas the prior doesn't necessarily force positioning. So in terms of flexibility, I would say the prior is better.